# Can ForkJoinPool be made any faster than ExecutorService in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7, fork-join

As long as I give ForkJoinPool **one extra thread** in the pool it performs equally faster as ExecutorService. Following are the three classes used: Main, RunnableTask and ForkJoinTask. Running on a 16 core box the program outputs following each time:
**Executor Time: 5002
ForkJoin Time: 5002**

Main Class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        runExecutor(80);
        runForkJoin(80);
    }

    public static void runForkJoin(int size) {
        ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool(17);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fjp.invoke(new ForkJoinTask(size));
        System.out.println("ForkJoin Time: "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        fjp.shutdown();
    }

    public static void runExecutor(int size) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(size);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < latch.getCount(); i++) {
            exec.submit(new RunnableTask(latch));
        }
        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Executor Time: "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Runnable class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class RunnableTask implements Runnable {
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public RunnableTask(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

RecursiveTask class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class ForkJoinTask extends RecursiveTask {
    private List<RecursiveTask> tasks;
    private int size;

    public ForkJoinTask(int size) {
        super();
        this.tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object compute() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            RecursiveTask task = new RecursiveTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object compute() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            task.fork();
            tasks.add(task);
        }

        for (RecursiveTask task : tasks) {
            task.join();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main interest of the fork-join pool is when each task calculates a subset of the final result and you can then easily merge the various subsets. In your case each calculation is independent so it does not make a difference (although I'm not sure why you need to use 17 instead of 16).

Comment: @assylias Isn't it 17 simply because there's one extra 'parent' thread waiting on 16 children that are doing stuff?  If you only had 16 total threads, then one forked task would have to wait for a thread to get done.

Comment: @sharakan  The `int` argument on the `ForkJoinPool` specifies the number of worker threads (see here: http://www.javac.info/jsr166z/jsr166z/forkjoin/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool(int)), so I would think that passing in `16` *should* result in one parent thread and 16 worker threads. But you are observing a performance impact from bumping the parallelism level to `17`?

Comment: @sharakan is correct in his explanation why its 17

Comment: @AndrewBissell I'm not the OP, so I'm not observing anything directly! I was under the impression that the parent task submitted using forkJoinPool.submit() is executed on one of the pool threads, which is therefore unavailable to be used to execute a child task.  I could be wrong, but the documentation you cited doesn't seem to clearly state one way or the other.

Comment: @AndrewBissell Interesting note: The JSR you linked to has the `int` constructor determining thread pool size.  The actual [Java7 javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool(int)) uses that `int` to determine 'parallelism', which I think boils down to "spawn enough threads to do 17 things at a time".  For the OP's case, same difference.

Comment: @sharakan  That *is* interesting. In looking through some of the source code here (http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166y/ForkJoinPool.java?view=co) it looks like the default setting on the parameterless constructor is `Runtime.availableProcessors`. But I don't know what parallelism level that would yield if it's called on a system with *x* cores and *y* number of busy threads.

Comment: Just confirmed in testing on my 4-core system that both the parameterless constructor and a specified parallelism level equal to `Runtime.availableProcessors()` results in the `ForkJoinPool` running with one fewer worker thread than `ExecutorService`. There must be some reason the default is set that way. Is there a cost to joining the parent thread with the `ForkJoinPool` which is lost in the sort of test created by the OP?

Comment: Looks like I am mixing the terms "worker" and "child" tasks interchangeably, when in fact the `ForkJoinPool` considers the parent task as one of its workers. I imagine this is important to its ability to scale more effectively than `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your individual tasks are such that **both** `ForkJoinPool` and an `ExecutorService` could be made to run faster than they are now, and further that neither one should have a substantial advantage over the other.

The reason why is that if a individual compute task is `Thread.sleep(1000)` then the task requires no CPU resources.  You could up the number of threads to match your job size (80) and complete 80 seconds of 'work' in somewhat more than 1 second elapsed time, because the threads would not really be competing for any kind of resources.

As for the comparison between `ForkJoinPool` and `ExecutorService`, the difference isn't relevant to your test case because your bits of work don't result in anything that should be the input to a further calculation (the 'reduce' step in [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)).  So to you, they're both just thread pools with a different API.